# Alternatives to AutoHotKey thats works with Synergy?

Tags: autohotkey, synergy, software-conflict

I'm trying to run AutoHotKey with [Synergy](http://synergy2.sourceforge.net/) to share keyboards and mouse on my work machine and gets an awesome custom shortcuts at the same time.

But I've expreienced problems as described in [this thread on AutoHotKey forum](http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/topic33744.html) .

So is there an alternative keyboard-mapper software like AutoHotKey that works with Synergy?

Comment: It's not that AHK doesn't work with Synergy.  You should know the problem they describe is not an issue with AutoHotKey, but an issue with Synergy.  I've had that issue with Synergy running by itself.  Alot of times I don't notice the "stuck" key until later.  You can reproduce the issue be holding Ctrl, moving mouse to another computer, and releasing the key.  The host computer never receives a "key up" message, and thus thinks the key is still held down.

Comment: @aaronls Thanks for the info :-) ... If you had made that an answer post, I'd have voted it up... Anyway I'm running AutoIt now... their scripting language is so much more intuitive

Comment: @aaronls ... I can't reproduce that... Hold Ctrl, move mouse to another machine, release Ctrl and then back... Ctrl is normal... with AutoIt ..

Comment: Every figure out a solution to this?  Right now I am using linux/ubuntu for basic one character remaps because synergy respects those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tried it with Synergy, but you could take a look at [AutoIT Script](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/). It performs the same basic purpose as AutoHotKey.

Comment: Didn't know about that app before. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2):

The [Synergy+](http://code.google.com/p/synergy-plus/) project is actively implementing new features. You could submit a [feature request](http://code.google.com/p/synergy-plus/issues/entry?template=Feature%20request).

Comment: Glad to see that you've forked this project! Keep up the great work. Hope you'll provide a proper fix for Synergy keyboard layout switching between Windows machines (see bug on sf.net with my hack for details).

Comment: Thanks! It's something we'll be working on once we've fixed the sticky keys problem. Take a look at this issue -  http://code.google.com/p/synergy-plus/issues/detail?id=5

Comment: @Nick Bolton Cool I'll help you test it : - )

Comment: chakrit: Great! I'd be happy to help in any way I can. Have you created a bug report? This would be much appreciated...

Comment: @Nick Boolton I've switched to AutoIt now... but I'll try to get a proper repro