# AutoHotKey doesn't work with Synergy?

Tags: autohotkey, synergy

I can use AutoHotKey to send some characters when a key combination is pressed.
The problem is that AutoHotKey doesn't seem to work with Synergy is used.

Is this true? I mean, does AutoHotKey work with Synergy or not?

And from [this](https://superuser.com/questions/23480/alternatives-to-autohotkey-thats-works-with-synergy) thread, I learned about AutoIt. How can I use AutoIt AHK way? I mean, how can I assign a key combination to send some sequence of characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you are using Synergy in two machines. Are you sure that Autohotkey is running  in both? If you have installed it in one, when you use Synergy to change to the other machine the key combination you made with AHK will not work.

Comment: @lther : I use Mac for server to have Windows as a clinet. Then, AHK will not work, is this correct?

Comment: I think it will not work. When you switch to Mac, the keyboard send keystrokes to it and will not pass through AHK first.